# Multipage layout content isn't refreshed on internal navigation link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using a multi page layout where each page has an img and p element that would be changed on the click of a next or previous button in order to act as a storybook. In the head section I have a case statement that picks up the localstorage value of the page id value.  I can't figure out how to refresh the page so that when I navigate to page 2 or higher the current page id value is found and then the correct text and image get assigned to the elements on the current page.  Will this be a performance nightmare if I reload the page on each next or previous click?  I'm creating a template to handle upto 20 case statement with each having 20 if else statements.

I can upload a code sample once I'm at a workstation.   Thanks

Comment: Without code it's difficult to spot the problem.

Comment: I ended up use inline script tags to print out the variable value.